# what kind of Hardware required for run geth private chain for ethereum on windows?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, etherscan

i need to help to find out what were the minimum hardware requirements needed for deploy the private chain on ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need this for development purposes, you can likely just use your laptop / desktop.

Here's a tutorial for setting up your own private network creating two local nodes on the same computer. (if you want PoW just select ethash when using puppeth)

https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8

Comment: thank for tutorial....i need this for deploy private block-chain. if you has any idea how much cpu, ram, disk space require then please share here...